# Deleting lead if its not active for 15 days

Tags: apex, trigger, scheduled-apex, time-dependent-workflow

I have a `Consent Obtained` Date field on the `Lead` object. If consent is not obtained (date field is null for 15 days), the `Lead` record and its associated `Activities` should automatically be deleted by the system. How can I achieve this?

Can I go with triggers or time based workflows, or do I need to write a batch job?

Answer (score 4):

You will want to write a batch and execute it daily. Your query locator should look like:

```
SELECT Id FROM Lead
WHERE CreatedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:15
AND Consent_Obtained__c = false
```

Then your execute method will just look like:

```
try
{
    delete scope;
}
catch (DmlException dmx)
{
    // send email? create log record?
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could make it a combination of workflow logic and trigger.

Workflow Rule

Evaluate when record is created or modified and meets the criteria.

Criteria: Date Consent Obtained equals null

Action: Time Based action (15 days after CreatedDate)

Field Update: Expired Lead -> Checked

```
trigger deleteExpiredLead on Lead (after update) {
    Lead[] deletes = new Lead[0];
    for(Lead record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.Expired_Lead__c) {
            deletes.add(new Lead(Id=record.Id));
        }
    }
    delete deletes;
}
```

Comment: Pls, advice--Consent Obtained Date is a Date field and while writing the rule,its not letting me to keep it null.  Error- Invalid Date(Valid Date Format. 5/6/2015).